# PHP email not getting sent with if statement

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use php to mail an email to a user if they check off a checkbox.
The email doesn't get sent. Can you use the `($_POST["receive-access"]) === checked`?

HTML:

```
<tr><td><p style="font-family:latine;">Email: </td><td><input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" style="font-family:latine;" required></p></td>
<br>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="receive-access" name="receive-access"></td>
<td><label for="receive-access">Check off this box for access to restricted areas.</label></td></tr>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $message = "Username: username Password: password";
    $recipient = $_POST["mail"];
    if(isset($_POST["receive-access"]) === checked)
    mail($recipient, "Restricted access username and password", $message);
?>
```

Comment: If the checkbox was not checked, it will not exist in the `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it hence checkbox won't exist in post if it is unchecked. Enjoy!

```
if(isset($_POST['receive-access']) && $_POST['receive-access'] == 'on')
{
   $_POST['receive-access'] = true;
}
else
{
   $_POST['receive-access'] = false;
}

$message = "Username: username Password: password";
$recipient = $_POST["mail"];
if(isset($_POST["receive-access"]) == true)
mail($recipient, "Restricted access username and password", $message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your messing up 2 kinds of if statements. What your looking for is this:

```
if(isset($_POST["receive-access"]) && $_POST["receive-access"] === checked)
```

The first statement `isset` will return `true` if the value is set. And then you have to check if the value equals to `checked`

But then again, if your `POST` value isset, the checkbox is checked. So the second part of the check isn't needed at all (probably won't work even)

So all you have to do is this:

```
if(isset($_POST["receive-access"]))
```

If you need more information about checkboxes and PHP, you could take a look at [this website](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html)

Comment: @dan08 maybe not if using === but don't think checked is a datatype

Comment: I'm new to php, so I don't really know.

Comment: @dan08, checked should indeed be between quotes. I was just pointing out what should be the if statement for what he was trying to do. I've edited my answer with the correct if statement on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Since the checkbox field "retrieve-access" will be only sent if is checked you could just do this.

```
if(isset($_POST["receive-access"]))
```